# Проверка на наличие решения в игру 15

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Помогите сообразить формулу/алгоритм для проверки наличия решения в `игре в 15`, но в общем виде. То есть мне бы формулу для поля размером 3х3, 5х5 и тд.
Вот что пишет [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B2_15#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) для 4х4:

> пусть квадратик с числом `i` расположен до (если считать слева направо и сверху вниз) `k` квадратиков с числами меньшими `i`. Будем считать `n[i] = k`, то есть если после костяшки с `i`-м числом нет чисел, меньших `i`, то `k=0`. Также введем число `e` — номер ряда пустой клетки (считая с 1). Если сумма
> [image: формула]
> является нечётной, то решения головоломки не существует.

Для 4х4 сумма должна быть четной для решаемости игры, то (дальше мое предположение) для полей 3х3, 5х5 и тд сумма должна быть нечетной для решаемости.
Ну и в моем решении `0` - считаю за пустой клеткой.

```js
// Проверяет игру на наличие решения.
function checkArrayForGame(arrayOrig) {
    let size = Math.sqrt(arrayOrig.length);
    let indZero = arrayOrig.indexOf(0);
    if (size !== parseInt(size) || indZero === -1) {
        console.log('Не верный формат аргументов');
        return false;
    }
    let N = parseInt(indZero / size) + 1; // на какой строке пустая клетка начиная с 1

    let array = arrayOrig.slice(); // make copy array;

    array.splice(indZero, 1); // удалил нолик из массива.
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
            N += array[i] > array[j];
        }
    }
    // console.log(size, N)
    return ((size % 2) && (N % 2))
            || (!(size % 2) && !(N % 2));
}

let testDataTrue = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0]
    ];
let testDataFalse = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 14, 0],
        [1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 0, 8, 2, 5] // для этого примера не работает =(
    ];
console.log('Must be True');
for (let i = 0; i < testDataTrue.length; ++i) {
    console.log('*', checkArrayForGame(testDataTrue[i]));
}
console.log('Must be False');
for (let i = 0; i < testDataFalse.length; ++i) {
    console.log('*', checkArrayForGame(testDataFalse[i]));
}
```

Спасибо за ответ @Harry. Попробовал реализовать по вашей формуле: [image: формула Harry]. Получился такой код:

```js
// Проверяет игру на наличие решения.
function checkArrayForGame(arrayOrig) {
    let size = Math.sqrt(arrayOrig.length);
    let indZero = arrayOrig.indexOf(0);
    if (size !== parseInt(size) || indZero === -1) {
        console.log('Не верный формат аргументов');
        return false;
    }
    let e = parseInt(indZero / size); // на какой строке пустая клетка начиная с 0

    let rightPart = (size - 1) * (e - 1) + 1;

    let array = arrayOrig.slice(); // make copy array;
    array.splice(indZero, 1); // удалил нолик из массива.

    let summ = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (let j = i; j < array.length; ++j) {
            summ += array[i] > array[j];
        }
    }
    let result = summ + rightPart;
    // console.log(size, e, rightPart, summ, result);
    //return ((size % 2) && (result % 2))
    //        || (!(size % 2) && !(result % 2));
    return result % 2;
}
let testDataTrue = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 0]
    ];
let testDataFalse = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 0],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 14, 0],
        [1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 0, 8, 2, 5] // для этого примера не работает =(
    ];
console.log('Must be True');
for (let i = 0; i < testDataTrue.length; ++i) {
    console.log('*', checkArrayForGame(testDataTrue[i]));
}
console.log('Must be False');
for (let i = 0; i < testDataFalse.length; ++i) {
    console.log('*', checkArrayForGame(testDataFalse[i]));
}
```

Comment: У вас как-то неоднозначно сформулирован ваш алгоритм... *после костяшки с i-м числом нет чисел* — это после костяшки с числом `i` на ней, или после костяшки на `i`-ом месте в ряду чисел?

Comment: Несколько раз перечитал, не понял вопроса. Алгоритм такой: Если после `i`ого элемента со значением `array[i]` есть элемент с меньшим значением (`array[i] > array[j]`, где `j > i`), то `N = N + 1`.

Comment: Стоят фишки в порядке `3 1 2 ` — по вашей терминологии "костяшка с 3-м числом" — это 3 или 2? А вообще по вопросу непонятно, что вас интересует — верно ли вы выбрали алгоритм? Правильно ри его реализовали? В чем конкретно вопрос?

Comment: А. `костяшки с i-м числом` - это видимо 3. А так, это не мой текст, а из википедии

Comment: В вики описана формула для поля 4х4. Для общего случая я не уверен что формула правильная. А в моей реализации есть ошибка: `[1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 0, 8, 2, 5]` - выдает что решение есть, хотя это не решаемая игра.

Comment: Ага, т.е. у вас вопрос не в алгоритме, а в реализации. Сказали бы сразу :) Тогда я умолкаю, JS — не мой язык.  Набросал и перепроверил. Нет, этот критерий для 5x5 точно не работает. Увы.

Comment: А для чего это надо? Был подобный вопрос, но с другого края. Там перемешивали фишки (или как их там) из исходного положения. Я сделал так, что N количество раз в пустую клетку перемещается случайная соседняя фишка. При этом в следующий раз она не перемещается чтобы не было туда-сюдалова. Для 4*4 100 таких случайных смещений нормально все перемешивали и гарантировалось, что есть возможность решить расклад. Если есть именно практическая надобность, то можно так и сделать. К сожалению, не могу найти это вопрос и ответ - скорее всего он был удален автором.

Comment: мне кажется случайное перемешивание + проверка + 1 замена (при необходимости исправить игру) - лучше, чем 100 перемешиваний для 4х4, 300 перемешиваний для 5х5 и тд. Ну если бы не было формулы и помощи, то пришлось бы так и делать)

Comment: @Leonid А как я, по-вашему, моделировал? :) Именно так и делал - гонял пустышку случайным образом... Лично меня заинтересовал сам вопрос, так сказать, теоретически, а не его практическое применение.

Comment: @KtoTo, даже 10000 перемещений будут достаточно хороши и останутся незаметными для пользователя, я уверен)) Я просто так и не понял всегда ли работает ваш алгоритм в итоге))) Предложил.

Comment: @Harry, я ваш интерес понял)) В итоге работает для любой доски? А если 4*8, например? Я сужу только по вашим же комментариям? Интересная задача)

Comment: @Leonid Не знаю. Но меня терзают не такие уж смутные подозрения :), что важна только **ширина** доски. Не хотите поиграть с моим кодом и проверить? :)

Comment: @Harry И в самом деле очень интересно с точки зрения математики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как показал эксперимент, для нечетных досок этот способ не работает.

Критерий должен быть некоторым иным.

Сам эксперимент можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ideone.com/Nasgvz), или скомпилировать самому (писано "на коленке", быстро и неэффективно, просто лишь бы проверить...).

Но! У меня есть **гипотеза**, основанная на некоторых соображениях из моего незнания :) теории чисел. Не могу ее ни доказать, ни опровергнуть... но эксперименты вроде проходит... Что брать вместо `e` надо не номер строки пустышки, а номер строки пустышки, считая с 0, умноженный на (N-1)

Т.е. вот эта сумма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должна для разрешимости иметь ту же четность, что и само значение *N* — размер доски. Но терзают меня сомнения, и даже не очень смутные, что гипотеза неверна...

Если кто опровергнет или докажет — буду крайне признателен...

**Update**

Для предложенного

```
1 7 4 6 3 0 8 2 5
```

где `0` — "пустышка", имеем:

Инверсий для 1 — 0, 2 — 0, 3 — 1, 4 — 2, 5 — 0, 6 — 3, 7 — 5, 8 — 2, итого сумма равна 13. Пустышка находится во 2 строке, значит, 13+2*1+1 = 16 — четно. N же равно 3 и нечетно. Итого, решения нет.

Вобщем, я гонял вычислительный эксперимент около получаса. Если правда то, что при перемене двух последних фишек мы получаем неразрешимую комбинацию, то за эти полчаса ни одного сбоя я не нашел. Конечно, вычислительный эксперимент — это не строгое математическое доказательство, но серьезная заявка на то, что это так и есть...

С кодом эксперимента можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/15.cpp).

Comment: В вашем примере `N` это размер доски?

Comment: Да, по одной стороне :)

Comment: Добавил код по вашей формуле. Правильно ли я реализовал? Ну и поведение такое же как и у моей реализации. `1 7 4 6 3 0 8 2 5` говорит что имеет решение.

Comment: У вас пустышка — 0? но ее нельзя учитывать в инверсиях вообще!

Comment: забыл нолик удалить. Ну и результат формулы если нечетный то есть решение(вне зависимости от размера). И теперь я попробовал пока только на тестовых данных все значения корректные. Дальше сейчас начну тестировать

Comment: Вот, разобрал ваш пример детально.

Comment: В вашем решении любые четные доски не отличаются от формулы вики. odd * (e-1) + 1 => e (even/odd). А вот для любых нечетных досок even * (e-1) + 1 => odd (всегда). И получается что результат от расположения пустышки не зависит. Надо проверять нечетные доски на результат. Можно тупо набить все возможные уникальные варианты перестановками, а потом каждый из вариантов проверить по формуле, если получится четное (то есть для нечетной доски недопустимый вариант), то формула неверна. Для 3*3, думаю, не так много вариантов, можно проверить будет))

Comment: @Leonid Да, конечно, можно и изменить — типа, `sum += (N%2-1)*e + 1;` Но просто я сначала нашел этот вариант чисто теоретически, а потом не стал менять — не надо ни `if`'ы разводить, ни еще какие-то преобразования :) В моем коде, думаю, 3x3 проверило насквозь — вряд ли какая позиция после миллиона движений осталась неиспытанной. Хотя шанс, конечно, остается. Ну проверьте вы.

Comment: То есть, для четных `e - 1 => !e`, а `odd * !e => !e` в итоге `!e + 1 => e`. Для четных `Сумма инверсий + e` сверяется с четом (размер доски). И получается, что то же. А вот для нечета: `N - 1 => even`, `even * any => even`, `even + 1 => odd`. Затем `Сумма инверсий + odd => !Сумма инверсий`. `!Сумма инверсий === !even`. В итоге просто для правильного решения для нечетной доски нужен четная сумма инверсий и все. Или я не так понял... В том смысле, что странно, что в этот раз позиция пустышек перестала учитываться...

Comment: Потому что при движении вверх четность количества инверсий не меняется.

Comment: Вроде да, все работает. При смене ряда на четных досках прибавляется/вычитается нечетное кол-во, поэтому нуждается в компенсации по порядковому номеру ряда. На нечетных досках прибавляется/вычитается четное кол-во, потому и разницы нет. Движение по горизонтали ничего для суммы не меняет. Сумма правильной исходной позиции 0, сумма при замене двух рядом стоящих номеров - 1. Все остальные операции лишь изменяют эти изначальные 1 (==нечет) или 0 (== чёт).

Comment: А любую нерешаемую позицию можно свести к переставленным соседним номерам (даже последней пары номеров), 14 и 15 для 4*4, например.